# WHM Custom nameservers not reacheable after Activating Cloudflare protection

Tags: cpanel, cloudflare, whm, nameservers

(All domain names used in this description are not real)

I have a hosting with WHM. The main domain is domain0.com. In that machine I host several domains and all of them use the same Nameservers automatically created by WHM.

domain1.com uses ns1.domain0.com as nameserver
domain2.com uses ns1.domain0.com as nameserver

I activated the Cloudflare protection and to do so I changed the  namservers for domain0.com in my registrar acording to Cloudflare's instructions.

The site domain0.com works great after the changes , and i can also access to domain0.com/whm BUT the problem is that domain1.com , domain2.com are no longer working.

when i ping the domains i get this.

ping: cannot resolve habemus.cl: Unknown host

Should i create new nameservers in WHM or should i make some configuration changes in cloudflare ?

I use the free version of Cloudflare.

Thanks in advance.

I tried adding an A record for ns1.domain0.com in cloudflares DNS section but it didn`t work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add each domain separately to the cloudflare, for each domain you will have a that the cloudflare will provide.

In cloudflare in the DNS configuration of each domain, you will need to add an entry A domainxxx.com pointing to the IP address of your WHM server.

if you want to use www. You must also configure a CNAME entry pointing to your domain "domainxxx.com"